# error reading pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a df which has `569 rows` and `125 columns` using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', header = None, sep = '\s+')
```

The output of `df.info()` is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 569 entries, 0 to 568
Columns: 125 entries, 0 to 124
dtypes: float64(123), int64(2)
memory usage: 560.1 KB
```

The output of `df` is:

```
0             1    2        3          4         5
0      0  0.000000e+00  773  19.7205  25.944920  0.205061  
1      1  1.000000e+00  772  19.7205  25.944920  0.205061
2      2  2.100000e+00  748  19.7205  25.944920  0.205061
3      3  3.310000e+00  763  19.7205  25.944920  0.205061
...
568  568  1.010799e+10  697  19.7205  25.524932  0.199651
```

When I write `print df['X.1']` **OR** `print df['1']` I am getting an error:

```
KeyError: 'X.1'
```

**OR**

```
KeyError: '1'
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your columns: `df.columns.tolist()` will show you what your columns really are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need to call `df[1]` because your columns are integers. You could check it calling `df.columns` with `dtype` of the index.
If you have something like this you need to call like integers:

```
In [214]: df.columns
Out[214]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

In [215]: df[1]
Out[215]: 
0    0.00
1    1.00
2    2.10
3    3.31
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

If you have column names as `str` you need to call `df['1']`:

```
In [216]: df.columns = map(str, range(1,6))

In [218]: df.columns
Out[218]: Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], dtype='object')

In [219]: df['1']
Out[219]: 
0    0.00
1    1.00
2    2.10
3    3.31
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake!! Thanks @Anton for the details.